# GPX based contours in QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour, gpx

I am an amateur orienteering mapper working on a complicated piece of ground. I can survey the ground with a very accurate GNSS RTK NTRIP connected receiver which records a GPX track. The GPX contains height information. How do I use QGIS to convert that GPX height information to contour lines?

Comment: If you have dense enough point measurements for elevation, you can interpolate a digital elevation model, then extract contours.

Comment: That's a useful thought, but how do I do it ? Any advice or hint welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As Babel said, you can interpolate your elevation data to generate a dem using interpolation algorithms like IDW or TIN and them extract the contour from the dem using the "contour" tool on QGIS

Comment: If you already post this as an answer, it would be great to elaborate on how to do it exactly as the OP seems not to be familiar with that (see comments).